# Why is "do" sometimes added to declarative sentences?

Tags: word-usage

Many people use the word *do* in statements, but I don't understand the significance of doing so.  For example, consider the following sentences:

> I know you.
> I ***do*** know you.
>
> I speak English.
> I ***do*** speak English.

I think both statements mean the same thing, but why does one include ***do***? Is there any purpose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called *do-support*.  It's required in a lot of places in English, but this isn't one of them.  Here, it's optional.

When you use *do* in this fashion, it emphasizes that something is true.  This is most commonly in response to a negative statement or question:

> **Q:** You don't like my dress, do you?
>   **A:** No, I ***do*** like it!  Ultraviolet looks lovely on you.

It can also be used to set up a contrast with another sort of negative:

> **Q:** You don't speak Japanese, then?
>   **A:** Well, I ***do*** speak Japanese, but not very well.

or

> **Q:** How do you like the food?
>   **A:** Well, I ***do*** like the kale, but I can't eat that much of it because I ate two gallons of ice cream for dinner.

Since this sort of *do-support* is optional, you could remove ***do*** from any of these examples and they'd still make sense.  They'd just be less emphatic.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support#For_emphasis) also talks about this sort of use and provides further examples.

Comment: Does that sentence mean the dress is invisible? I cannot see ultraviolet rays. `;)`

Comment: Who said it was a human uttering the sentence? ;-)

Comment: OK, OK, they are non humans practicing their English. I wonder when I will see an alien practicing its Italian. `;)`

Comment: [The Emperor's New Clothes](http://www.andersen.sdu.dk/vaerk/hersholt/TheEmperorsNewClothes_e.html), anyone? ;) @kiamlaluno